# Scan or read text to initiate a video clip

Tags: iphone

I need help in playing video by scanning a text message. I have been googling however, the only thing which I am getting is through QR codes. Please let me know if its possible or not. If possible can you please share examples of the same or sites to refer. I am working on iOS to develop this program.

Regards,

Mike

Comment: You want to use the camera to scan a line of text and with a algorithm (or something) read it? Am I correct?

Comment: Thanks for your response to answer your question Yes and I am looking to use AR however, still confused which libraries to use. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is something worth checking out: [Tesseract-iPhone-Demo](https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo)